# Netflix in Android WebView

Tags: android, android-webview

So let me preface this by saying downloading the Netflix App is not an option.  So my thought is to just make a wrapper app that loads the netflix website in a WebView.  This works for login/navigation; however, whenever you hit the play button to start playing the video, there is no response and no output in logcat.  I'm looking for a way to see more debug messages from the WebView or a way to get the video playing.  Using Android 4.4.4 by the way.

```
View layout = LayoutInflater.from(mActivity).inflate(R.layout.main_layout, vContentAreaContainer, false);

WebView webView = (WebView) layout.findViewById(R.id.main_web_view);
            webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

webView.loadUrl("http://www.netflix.com");
vContentAreaContainer.addView(layout);
```

Comment: Netflix use html 5, so i think the best way is to find some info about webview and its html 5 support especially with vídeo streaming

Comment: I did some investigating into that.  It seems like all you need to do for HTML 5 video to work is enable hardware acceleration.  I've done that, but still no luck.

Answer (score 11):

It's a old question but leaving this answer here in the hope that it may help others.

**TL;DR:** Netflix content can't be played in Android-Webviews because Android-Webviews don't support the widevine license security-level required for Netflix videos playback.

Details:

- HTML5 players use Encrypted Media Extension APIs to check the security-level (robustness) supported by widewine CDM of Android-Webview.
- The navigator API to find supported widevine configuration is [requestMediaKeySystemAccess](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/requestMediaKeySystemAccess). We see this API being used by akira.js player in netflix website. Adding a breakpoint here we see that the parameters passed to requestMediaKeySystemAccess is:

  ```
    [{
      "distinctiveIdentifier": "not-allowed",
      "initDataTypes": [
        "cenc"
      ],
      "persistentState": "required",
      "videoCapabilities": [
        {
          "contentType": "video/mp4; codecs=\"avc1.640028\"",
          "robustness": "HW_SECURE_DECODE"
        },
        {
          "contentType": "video/mp4; codecs=\"avc1.640028\"",
          "robustness": "SW_SECURE_DECODE"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "distinctiveIdentifier": "not-allowed",
      "initDataTypes": [
        "cenc"
      ],
      "persistentState": "required"
    }]
  ```
- The minimum robustness level requuired for netflix videos playback is SW_SECURE_DECODE as described above.
- If we open the Android WebView console and check the robustness-level required by NetFlix videos we see the following error: `unsupported keySystem or supportedConfiguration`

[image]

Comment: I raised a bug on the Android Issue Tracker & they clarified that WebView won't support Widevine beyond L3, effectively making WebView Video Playback on Netflix as not possible.

Comment: Bug: [Supporting Widevine L1/L2 in Android WebView](https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/192911450).

Comment: Response from Google
`Status: Won't Fix (Infeasible) Unfortunately WebView just does not currently support Widevine beyond L3 as it requires a more complex rendering mechanism to be implemented, and this is not currently on our roadmap as far as I am aware. Apps which need more advanced video capabilities on Android typically use ExoPlayer from the embedding app code.`

Answer (score 3):

You can load Netflix in Android Webview but wont be able to play Netflix videos because:

- if user agent is mobile device than Netflix will use intent based url
  schema. This intents are handled by Netflix app and if device dont have Netflix installed to handle them then "install Netflix screen" will be shown.
- If you manually set user agent to desktop then Netflix will ask to install **Microsoft Silverlight Plugin** which is available only for Mac and Windows. So again you will reach a dead end.

  ```
       webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false)

       val newUA = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12) 
           AppleWebKit/602.1.50 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Safari/602.1.50"

      webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(newUA)
  ```

Comment: How does apps like Rave lets you play Netflix videos on android.?

Comment: @PrashantSharma did you find any solution?