# How to play prime or Netflix video in mobile developer player (flutter/ios/android/reactnative)?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, html5-video, netflix

There is no open API of Prime video or Netflix, but the App Rave https://rave.io/ open videos in their app after login to prime or Netflix. Rave include many provider so i don't think that can be private partnership, so there must be some ways to play those video in our player of application. Is anyone have idea how to play those video in flutter/ios/android ?

In Rave they used webview for login to prime, Netflix and other provider , and as per my study prime and Netflix used DRM to protect videos,
but there are some players also support DRM (i think [Shakaplayer](https://github.com/google/shaka-player)) is one of them, but i am not sure wether will it work or not? if it's work then how we can get DRM related data from browser session ?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35285671/netflix-in-android-webview

Answer (score 2):

The DRM used for a given service is designed to only deliver the licensee to an app or devices which has been verified to be associated with an authorised logged in user.

In other words the DRM encrypts the licensee (which includes the content key itself) it is delivering with a key which the authorised device or client can decrypt, and which others can't.

Unless you have a partnering agreement or similar with the service provider you will not be authorised like this, so, unless you plan in pirating the content, can't play the video.